# No Response Drop to root shell prompt

Tags: grub2

Im trying to reset my ubuntu forgot password but when I enter into GRUB and press enter Root( drop to root shell prompt) there's not appear prompt to enter command. what should I do ?

Comment: Are you aware that by resetting the password you WON'T have access to your personal files anyway? If that is your goal then better to accept your losses and start over, it takes a lot less time.

Comment: you mean installation ubuntu again sir ? if it's so how to remove previous version completely ? Im trying my best to use ubuntu for my work but I dont know and Im stuck here

Comment: You don't need to remove anything before booting the installer and you can even reuse the partitions.

Answer (score 1):

After selecting *root  Drop to root shell prompt* from the Recovery menu press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key twice instead of once to show the root prompt.

[image]